# how do I Update mysql table from one-table to another?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have the following tables..

```
Table A:

id_A    col1
 1      val1
 2      val2
 3      val3
 ...    ....

Table B:

id_B   col2   
 4     val2    
 5     val3     
 6     null     
...    ...      

Table C:

id_A    id_B
 1      4
 2      5
 3      6
 ...    ....
```

what I need is, I want to copy from table-A to Table-B. how do i do that?
Help please?

****how could I update Table A id_A 1 to Table B? according to Table C the id_A 1 == id_B 4,****

from the above query the output will be...

Table B will update...

Table B:

```
 id_B   col2   
     4     val1   // here is changed because updated from table A    
     5     val3     
     6     null     
    ...    ...
```

Comment: what is condition ? it would be `insert into tableA (select * from tableB)` without this...

Comment: let's say i want to copy from table A id_A 1 to Table B, how do i achieve that?

Comment: because the table A and B are connected over the third table C. that is the problem i have...

Comment: how could I update Table A id_A 1 to Table B? according to Table C the id_A 1 == id_B 4, that means when i update from table A to B, we should only update the exact id.

Comment: Your requirements are ... well ... hard to understand. As you have an example of *input* data, could you update your question to show us the *expected output*. Without at least that, the "update-according-to-table-C" thing is quite incomprehensible.

Comment: @MrInternet but in Your example data  A`2=val2` in C 2 is related to 5 but in B`5=val3`

Comment: ok, please copy for id_A 1...???

Answer (score 1):

if this would work, it's trivial

```
UPDATE tableB b, (SELECT id_A AS id_prov ,a.val FROM tableA a, tableC c 
WHERE    a.id_A=c.id_A ) a
SET b.val=a.val WHERE id_B=id_prov
```

Answer (score 1):

This will update table_b.col2 with the associated value from table_a.col1:

```
UPDATE table_b b
  JOIN table_c c
    ON c.id_B = b.id_B
  JOIN table_a a
    ON a.id_A = c.id_A
   SET b.col2 = a.col1
 WHERE b.id_B = 4
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo** here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6203f/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6203f/1)

**NOTE:**

The example data shows the only table_b row updated is `id_B = 4`. The rows `(5,'val3')` and `(6,null)` are unchanged, even though there are associated rows in table_a.

The purpose of the WHERE clause in the query above is to prevent rows other than `id_B = 4` from being updated.

The rather odd naming of the tables and columns, and the confusingly similar values makes the example difficult to decipher.

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:**  if the column i have is more than one? how could i set?

**A:** To update an additional column in the same statement, then include an assignment of an expression to that column in the SET clause.  Refer to the "Multi-table syntax" in the MySQL Documentation for details.

[**MySQL Documentation** here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Comment: SET b.col2 = a.col1, if the column i have is more than one? how could i set?